# ZF2- Access a module's route only if authenticated

Tags: php, authentication, routes, zend-framework2

I have 2 modules on my `Zend MVC application`. I want to set the routes for the Administration module accessable only if the user is authenticated as admin.

Is there any general method to know who is authenticated when dispatching an `URL` ? If it's not the admin redirict him to an error page.

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [mvc event](http://www.zendframework.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html) like "dispatch". Listen to this event in bootstrap-method of Module.php (e.g.) and call a custom method that processes authentication/redirecting. So, here is a little example: Maybe, you will also have a look at authentication services.

```
/**
* /Admin/src/Admin/Module.php (e.g.)
*/
class Module
{
   public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
     /* @var $sharedEventManager \Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager */
     $sharedEventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
     $sharedEventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'doAuthentication'),1); // 1 is priority
   }

   /**
    * authentication processing
    */
   public function doAuthentication($event) {
      // your logic....
   }
}
```

Comment: Effectively this is the solution I need. I found also this [http://pastebin.com/FFGVCpki]. Thanks !

Comment: Only one problem this also applicated to the other module. So how to make it specific to the Administration module ?

Comment: Right, because you attach the event to every ActionController.
Maybe create an AdminController extending from AbstractActionController. The AdminController contains the event identifier: 
protected $eventIdentifier = ___CLASS___;

Extend your ActionControllers from AdminController and listen in Module::bootstrap to:
$sharedEvents->attach('Namespace\To\AdminController', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, "..."));

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use bjyauthorize instead of rolling your own.

https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

Comment: Yes I think it's a better solution. But I'm just trying to do a small application for a homework.